# What's the best way to name a predicate function?

Tags: coding-style

I'm looking at a function called:

```
WhetherAddFloor(leg) -> bool
```

and when I see code like:

```
if(WhetherAddFloor(l)) ...
```

it smells odd and am wonder if something like:

```
CheckAddFloorNeeded(leg) -> bool
```

wouldn't be better? Thoughts?

Comment: I would keep the concept of "adding a floor" separate from "floor needed".  `if (FloorNeeded(leg)) { AddFloor(); }`

Answer (score 13):

In languages where question marks are allowed in function names the style is to append one to the end if the function returns boolean:

```
FloorNeeded?(leg)
```

But where that isn't syntactically possible the convention is to use the word 'is' at the beginning:

```
isFloorNeeded(leg)
```

It's generally easy to read and understand and it seems like it'll fit your situation.

Comment: You can't use a question mark with a function name. Can you use it?

Comment: @Lion, yes, you can. Examples are, among others, Clojure and Ruby.

Comment: Ho! I didn't really know this.

Answer (score 1):

`WhetherAddFloor()` sounds as quite an unfortunate choice to me.

`CheckAddFloorNeeded()` is better, if the function has a substantial amount of work to do, and you would like to advertise that fact to those who use the interface.

`IsFloorNeeded()` is also good, if the function does not have a substantial amount of work to do, (say, it is just an accessor to a previously computed member,) or if you want to keep this little bit of information secret from those using the interface.